# Strict Standards: Declaration of ' ' should be compatible with ' '

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I just installed woocommerce 2.0 (on Wordpress) on PHP 5.4, and I got this:

> **Strict Standards**: Declaration of WC_Gateway_BACS::process_payment()
>   should be compatible with WC_Payment_Gateway::process_payment() in
>   D:\my\path\to\htdocs\wordpress\plugins\woocommerce\classes\gateways\bacs\class-wc-gateway-bacs.php
>   on line...

I check the files and found that `WC_Payment_Gateway` have no method `process_payment()`.
I need to know how to resolve this (not by setting `error_reporting()`).

What is ***Strict Standards*** in PHP exactly?
In what condition so we get that error?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`WC_Payment_Gateway` is defined in `abstract-wc-payment-gateway.php` and declares a method

```
function process_payment() {}
```

while `WC_Gateway_BACS` defines it as

```
function process_payment( $order_id ) { ...
```

(maybe you mixed up WC_Payment_Gateway and WC_Payment_Gateway**s**).

So, different signature (0 parameters vs 1 parameter) -> strict error.
Since it seems* to be used always with one parameter you could change

```
function process_payment() {}
```

to

```
function process_payment($order_id) {}
```

---

(*) keep in mind I know of woocommerce only since the last five minutes, so don't take my word for it.

Comment: thanks for the explain, maybe you want to check the parent: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-payment-gateways.php , and the child: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/gateways/bacs/class-wc-gateway-bacs.php , the child have `process_payment()` but it's parent doesn't. I tried add that function to the parent but I still get the error.

Comment: `WC_Payment_Gateways` is not the base class, `WC_Payment_Gateway` is; as noted in my answer text.

Comment: just realized there is `abstract` folder, :D . Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

**Quote from PHP Manual**

> In PHP 5 a new error level E_STRICT is available. Prior to PHP 5.4.0 E_STRICT was not >included within E_ALL, so you would have to explicitly enable this kind of error level in >PHP < 5.4.0. Enabling E_STRICT during development has some benefits. STRICT messages >provide suggestions that can help ensure the best interoperability and forward >compatibility of your code. These messages may include things such as calling non-static >methods statically, defining properties in a compatible class definition while defined in >a used trait, and prior to PHP 5.3 some deprecated features would issue E_STRICT errors >such as assigning objects by reference upon instantiation.

You are receiving this error because **WC_Gateway_BACS::process_payment()** declaration is different than **WC_Payment_Gateway::process_payment()** (might be not the same amount of parameters etc). If **WC_Payment_Gateway** has no method process_payment, check it's parent class :)

Also, if you want to disable STRICT errors, add **^ E_STRICT** to your error reporting configuration, for example:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
```

Answer (score 8):

if you wanna keep OOP form without turning any error off, you can also:

```
class A
{
    public function foo() {
        ;
    }
}
class B extends A
{
    /*instead of : 
    public function foo($a, $b, $c) {*/
    public function foo() {
        list($a, $b, $c) = func_get_args();
        // ...

    }
}
```

Comment: Ugly as hell, but sometime needed.

Comment: This is never needed.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using the same function in a parent class and a child class, but the child class needs parameters while the parent one not, you'll get the `Strict Standards` error.

**Example**

Manager:

```
public function getAtPosition($position)
{
    foreach ($this->getList() as $obj)
    {
        if ($obj->getPosition() == $position)
            return $obj;
    }

    return null;
}
```

MenuManager extends Manager:

```
public function getAtPosition($position, $parent)
{
    foreach ($this->getList() as $m)
    {
        if ($m->getParent() == $parent && $m->getPosition() == $position)
            return $m;
    }

    return null;
}
```

This example will generate an error:

> Strict standards: Declaration of MenuManager::getAtPosition() should
>   be compatible with Manager::getAtPosition($position)

Because we don't have the same arguments to the function, so let's trick this and add arguments, even though we're not using them!

Manager:

```
public function getAtPosition($position, $dummy = 0) // Dummy to avoid Strict standards errors
{
    foreach ($this->getList() as $obj)
    {
        if ($obj->getPosition() == $position)
            return $obj;
    }

    return null;
}
```

MenuManager extends Manager:

```
public function getAtPosition($position, $parent = 0)
{
    foreach ($this->getList() as $m)
    {
        if ($m->getParent() == $parent && $m->getPosition() == $position)
            return $m;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Only one to be careful is that when using `getAtPosition()` from `MenuManager.class.php`, be sure you are actually sending 2 parameters, as we have to declare `$parent = 0` in order to match the parent's declaration.

Every class extending `Manager` and not containing `getAtPosition()` will use the method from `Manager`.

If declared in a child class, php will use the method from the child class instead of the parent's one. There is no `overloading` in PHP, so that is how I worked around it until it is properly implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better answer   -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9243127/2165415

for example,

`parentClass::customMethod($thing = false)`  and

 `childClass::customMethod($thing)`

 so, when you call `customMethod()` for the class, it may trigger the error, because the child's method hasn't defined a default value for the first argument.