# Gravity-forms Better Pre-submission Confirmation not working

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I am using gravity forms on my wordpress site and using the code from
http://gravitywiz.com/better-pre-submission-confirmation/
to get the pre-submission confirmation page. I have done as instructed but there are no additional merge tags displaying in the HTML field apart from the standard ones.

I am getting the following errors on setting wp_debug mode to true.

Strict Standards: Declaration of GFCategoryWalker::start_el() should be compatible with Walker::start_el(&$output, $object, $depth = 0, $args = Array, $current_object_id = 0)

Non-static method GWPreviewConfirmation::init() should not be called statically

I don't really understand these errors and not able to find any documentation about it in relation to gravity forms.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the second of these issues looks like something to do with the PHP version. This post about a similar issue on get_base_path() suggests just adding the `static` keyword before `function  init`:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/debug-error-message

Edit: see here for explanation of the declaration should be compatible...
[Strict Standards: Declaration of ' ' should be compatible with ' '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234259/strict-standards-declaration-of-should-be-compatible-with)